# Double form will not submit second form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hi I have two HTML forms when the one is submit a JavaScript function submits the second the one form works but the second doesn't I'm not sure if it is the forms or the post pages can any one help.

The one form sends an email this is sending the email correctly sending the correct data to the correct email address.

The second form is meant to upload a file it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all there are now errors displayed to the screen I have done a try catch and nothing is displayed i have also looked into the logs and nothing is displayed I'm

HTML

```
        <div id="loginborder">


        <form id ="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_logo.php" method="POST">
                        <input name="userfile" type="file" />
                        <input type="submit" onsubmit="alert()"  value="dont press" disabled>
        </form>

            <div id="login">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Can you create me a Contributors account">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company Name">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tc" onclick= "checkbox()">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" onsubmit="alert()" name="submit" value="Register" disabled>
                </form>



    </div>
        </div>

        <?php 
            }
            else
            // the user has submitted the form
            {
            // Check if the "subject" input field is filled out
                if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
                {
                    sleep(5);
                    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
                    $first = $_POST["first_name"];
                    $company = $_POST["company"];
                    $therest = "First name= $first" . "\r\n" . "Company= $company" . "\r\n";          
                }
                    echo "$therest <br>";
                    $first = wordwrap($first, 70);
                    mail("careersintheclassroom01@gmail.com",$subject,$name,$therest,"subject: $subject\n");
                    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
                    header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                function alert() 
                {
                document.getElementById("upload").submit();
                }

                function checkbox(){
                    if (document.getElementById("tc").checked == true)
                        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
                    else
                        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                }

                $('input[placeholder],input[placeholder],input[placeholder],input[placeholder],input[placeholder]').placeholder();
            </script>
```

Upload_Logo.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
</html> 

<?php
    $uploaddir = "./images/"; 

    echo $uploaddir;
    mkdir($uploaddir, true);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo "<br />";
    echo " <b>Your media has been uploaded</b><br /><br /> ";
?>
```

the `<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>` on the second form calls the php at the bottom of the page this is the one that is working it is the upload_logo.php that is not currently working any help would be much appreciated

Comment: please be more specific on what "is not currently working" means.. do you get any error messages (displayed on the site or in the logs)?

Comment: I have updated the question @John but no there are no errors either displayed on the screen or within the logs i have tried to put a try catch around the function but it displays nothing any ideas ?? im not sure if it is actually getting to the php page because it doesnt seem to try to upload the file

Comment: I think the problem is your "alert" function (`onsubmit="alert()"`). **alert** is defined by the webbrowser (Standard!) and provides an modal dialog.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss at the top I specified a function called alert so should it not call that usually the box would be within the function like this `Alert("hello");`

Comment: Sure, but you can have problems in other browsers. In your browser it seems to be work,... Rename the method/function and you are on the secure side. `Alert("hello");` and `alert("hello");` is the same for many browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to submit 2 forms at once. That can't work, as your browser can only be directed to 1 page at a time, so your attempt to submit the upload form with JavaScript is cancelled by the contact form being submitted. I'd suggest that you move the file input into the same form as the contact fields, and handle them both in your "the user has submitted the form" section.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    ?>
    <div id="loginborder">
        <div id="login">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <input name="userfile" type="file" />
                <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Can you create me a Contributors account">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company Name">
                <input type="checkbox" id="tc" onclick="checkbox()">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register" disabled>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php 
        }
        else
        // the user has submitted the form
        {
        // Check if the "subject" input field is filled out
            if (!empty($_POST["subject"]))
            {
                sleep(5);
                $subject = $_POST["subject"];
                $first = $_POST["first_name"];
                $company = $_POST["company"];
                $therest = "First name= $first" . "\r\n" . "Company= $company" . "\r\n";          
                echo "$therest <br>";
                $first = wordwrap($first, 70);
                mail("careersintheclassroom01@gmail.com",$subject,$name,$therest,"subject: $subject\n");
                echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
                header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );
            }

            if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
                $uploaddir = "./images/"; 
                if (!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
                    mkdir($uploaddir, true);
                }
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                echo "<br />";
                echo " <b>Your media has been uploaded</b><br /><br /> ";
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok any idea how i would do this im not sure how i would combine the two without it clashing against each other @Niall

Comment: Ok, I've moved some of your code around to form a solution for you which is handling both sets of inputs being in the same form.

Comment: when trying your example i get a 500 internal server error but i cannot find anything in the logs @Niall

Comment: The snippet I posted was adapted from yours, but I added the "if" at the start which was implied by your "else" in the middle - if you copied and pasted mine in, make sure you don't have 2 opening "if"s now.

Comment: Oh, haha, I also just noticed a typo in mine - I was missing a closing bracket on that first "if" - I've edited my post to correct it.

Comment: thats great it is fully working now one question i was curious on in your example you do not use `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"` did it actually need that or have you used something else that gives you the same results ??

Comment: An HTML form will submit to the current page by default if you don't give it an action, so you don't really need to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

try this after `$uploadfile = ...`

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

Comment: this did not work I'm starting to think that Niall's idea may be the problem any ideas how i would put the two forms together

Answer (score 0):

when you submit 2nd form e-mail would be generated becausue it triggers `if(isset($_POST["subject"]))` condition and the code will follow the next commands.

But when you submit 1st form, it will call `onsubmit="alert();` function and that function again submits the same form because of these.

```
function alert() 
                {
                document.getElementById("upload").submit();
                }
```

so you are just triggering a never ending loop.

My solution is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alert() 
                {


                function checkbox(){
                    if (document.getElementById("tc").checked == true)
                        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
                    else
                        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                }
                 }

                $('input[placeholder],input[placeholder],input[placeholder],input[placeholder],input[placeholder]').placeholder();
            </script>
```

I'am not 100% sure about your requirement. hope you can get the point what i'am making. gl!

Comment: this is a good solution but by the looks of it i need a solution like putting the two forms together as Niall suggested any ideas on how i can do this ??